# Accidentally deleted Windows 7 Boot sector / MBR

Tags: windows-7, boot, bootloader, mbr

Accidentally run the following on system drive instead of USB.
OS: Windows 7. 1 system partition and 1 unformatted partition.
Now still haven't rebooted while writing this. 
On C disk root can see `BOOTSECT.BAK`. Not sure if I only damaged MBR or also boot sector.

[image]

How to recover Windows 7 loader without Windows recovery disk, inside working OS?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your best option would be to find a Windows recovery disk. There is a utility on the recovery disk called bootsect.exe:

```
C:\Data>bootsect

bootsect {/help|/nt60|/nt52} {SYS|ALL|<DriveLetter>:} [/force] [/mbr]

Boot sector restoration tool

Bootsect.exe updates the master boot code for hard disk partitions in order to
switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR.  You can use this tool to restore the boot
sector on your computer.

Run "bootsect /help" for detailed usage instructions.
```

If you do not have a recovery disk you can attempt to download the executable itself from elsewhere, however I cannot vouch for the legitimacy of any website purporting to offer downloads of Microsoft .exe's:

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bootsect.exe

The utility can be run from inside a working OS but isn't included in a standard install - hence getting it is the problem.